# Cloud function listening to GMail stops listening after a while (a week or so)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, gmail

I currently have code virtually identical to [this](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/gcf-gmail-codelab/blob/master/auth/index.js) running in a cloud function. Everything works. It works. Then, after about a week, it'll stop working, and I'll have to reauthorize it, that is to say go to `auth_init` again. As I go through the process, it will tell me something like cloud functions already have access. When I complete the process and authorize, it'll tell me I've successfully authorized and work for another week. How do I make the cloud function listen to the e-mails in perpetuity?

Answer (score 0):

You must re-call [watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) at least every 7 days or else you will stop receiving updates for the user. We recommend calling watch once per day. The watch response also has an expiration field with the timestamp for the watch expiration. You can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#renewing_mailbox_watch) for reference.